# Fatal Error: attempting to read the result set

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I always Encounter this problem, but the query is working as trying in my workbench. where it could be possibly wrong in my code?

```
Dim sqlcmd1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM attendance_master", conn)
            Dim dr1 As MySqlDataReader
            dr1 = sqlcmd1.ExecuteReader
            If dr1.HasRows Then
                While dr1.Read
                    Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()

                    newitem.Text = dr1.Item("Personnel_id").ToString
                    newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("in_time").ToString)
                    newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("out_time").ToString)


                    LvCompare.Items.Add(newitem)
                End While
            End If
```

Comment: Can you post the complete exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove ALL spaces:

myString = myString.Replace(" ", "")

To remove leading and trailing spaces:

myString = myString.Trim()

Comment: How does this answer the question?  I don't see anything in the question about removing spaces.  Could this answer have been posted to the wrong question?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there are nulls in your result set. There are many ways to deal with nulls. DBNull is one way. Here I just added an empty string to the value. It will not hurt a real value and CStr should accept the null with the empty string appended.

```
    newitem.Text = CStr("" & dr1.Item("Personnel_id"))
    newitem.SubItems.Add(CStr("" & dr1.Item("in_time")))
    newitem.SubItems.Add(CStr("" & dr1.Item("out_time")))
```